# Python Data Structure for Treebank?

Tags: python, nltk, corpus, nlp

I'm looking for a Python data structure that handles the Penn Treebank structure. This is a sample of what the Treebank looks like:

```
( (S
    (NP-SBJ (PRP He) )
    (VP (VBD shouted) )
    (. .) ))
```

Essentially, I would like a data structure that I can ask things like "What are the children of the subject NP?" or "What types of phrases dominate the pronoun?", preferably in Python. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 3):

[NLTK modules](http://nltk.org) might be a good start to implement Penn Treebank and other NLP related stuff  in Python.

Comment: Thanks Praveen. I've actually dealt with NLTK before, but I can't seem to find anything that really helps me here. Think I'm going to have to write my own structure, which actually is no big deal per se, I'm just struggling with how to parse the corpus properly, that is identifying a node's children et cetera.

Answer (score 1):

I still suggest using NLTK to read the treebank (see e.g. [this blog post](http://freecode.com/articles/processing-corpora-with-python-and-the-natural-language-toolkit)), but I can imagine it doesn't support this kind of general queries.

> "What are the children of the subject NP?"

This would be a `dict`, say `children`, mapping nonterminals to `sets` of either nonterminals or child nodes.

> "What types of phrases dominate the pronoun?"

This would be another `dict`, say `parents`, mapping nonterminals to `sets` of nonterminals.

You might want to build a relational database of tree nodes. The exact schema would depend on what kind of queries you want to ask, but be sure to check out the Python [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) module.

Alternatively, you can recode the treebank in XML and [use XPath to query it](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.77.5883&rep=rep1&type=pdf). [LXML](http://lxml.de) is the best XML/XPath library for Python, IMHO.